# Justify-content aligns single line text but not when the text spans multiple lines

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to understand flexbox alignment better, so I tried to align content with only flexbox features. I tried to align the text by using nested flexbox, but I don't understand why justify-content centers items that have single line of text (flex-item-1 and flex-item-5), but not the other flex items. What am I missing?

Here's my CSS example!
https://codepen.io/altroboy/pen/NWXNBxZ

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50vh;
  background: hsl(120, 0%, 80%);
  justify-content: center;
}

.flex-item {
  flex: 0 1 30%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.flex-item-1 {
  background: hsl(0, 80%, 50%);
}

.flex-item-2 {
  background: hsl(60, 80%, 50%);
}

.flex-item-3 {
  background: hsl(120, 80%, 50%);
}

.flex-item-4 {
  background: hsl(180, 80%, 50%);
}

.flex-item-5 {
  background: hsl(240, 80%, 50%);
}

.flex-item-6 {
  background: hsl(300, 80%, 50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-item flex-item-1">11111 11111 11111 11111</div>
  <div class="flex-item flex-item-2">22222 22222 33333 22222 22222 22222 22222</div>
  <div class="flex-item flex-item-3">33333 33333 33333 33333 33333 33333 33333 33333 33333 33333</div>
  <div class="flex-item flex-item-4">44444 44444 44444 44444 44444 44444 44444 44444 44444 44444 </div>
  <div class="flex-item flex-item-5">55555 55555 55555 55555 </div>
  <div class="flex-item flex-item-6">66666 66666 66666 66666 66666 66666 66666 66666 66666 66666 </div>
</div>
```

(I'm new to this, let me know if I should add any more info!)

Comment: Hello @OneDay, do you want the first line to be in the center and the second row in the same div to go to the center again?

Comment: Hey @AwatITWork, I would like all the 6 items to be centered horizontally using justify-content:center. Currently only items 1 and 5 are centered (seems like it is because they only span across one line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me know if I am doing it wrong,
well, the reason for that is each of your container flex-item-1 ... flex-item-6 has a width and height and run out of width in this case, the remaining will move to **Left**  here if you want to align that to **center** you just need to use

```
text-align: center !important;
```

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50vh;
  background: hsl(120, 0%, 80%);
  justify-content: center;
}

.flex-item {
  flex: 0 1 30%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.flex-item-1 {
  background: hsl(0, 80%, 50%);
}

.flex-item-2 {
  background: hsl(60, 80%, 50%);
  text-align: center !important;
}

.flex-item-3 {
  background: hsl(120, 80%, 50%);
  text-align: right !important;
}

.flex-item-4 {
  background: hsl(180, 80%, 50%);
}

.flex-item-5 {
  background: hsl(240, 80%, 50%);
}

.flex-item-6 {
  background: hsl(300, 80%, 50%);
  text-align: center !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-item flex-item-1">11111 11111 11111 11111</div>
  <div class="flex-item flex-item-2">22222 22222 33333 22222 22222 22222 22222</div>
  <div class="flex-item flex-item-3">33333 33333 33333 33333 33333 33333 33333 33333 33333 33333</div>
  <div class="flex-item flex-item-4"><span style="text-align: justify">44444 44444 44444 44444 44444 44444 44444 44444 44444 44444 44444 44444 44444 44444 44444 44444 44444 44444 44444 44444 44444 44444 44444 44444 44444 44444 44444 44444 44444 44444 </span></div>
  <div class="flex-item flex-item-5">55555 55555 55555 55555 </div>
  <div class="flex-item flex-item-6">66666 66666 66666 66666 66666 66666 66666 66666 66666 66666 </div>
</div>
```

[image: My Result]

if you want to display them all as **one-line** you can apply it with **font-size: x-small;**

[image: Font-size]

Comment: Hmm.. I think I get what you mean. So even though the text is broken down into the next line and does not look like it is taking the full width, it is actually treated as taking up the full width because they are all "text"?

Comment: @OneDay, yes but not full width, for better understanding try adding a **span** tag with so many 44444 just like you have done, and then set the 
**width: 100% !important;
text-align: justify;
** 
this will get all the available width it renders like it **contain** the div

let me update the answer for that.

Comment: Thanks! I got what you mean. The text are still treating as one whole chunk even though they are broken into multiple lines. The text-align:justify helped to see it more clearly too. Thanks! I tried breaking down the text into multiple divs and that worked as expected. My misconception is that the text is treated as separate "elements" just because it went to the next line.

Comment: @OneDay You are welcome, yes still all the text is one, to better understand this as you already did, place the whole text inside another tag, still, it is one i.e span or h2, also this **display behavior might be** different from one browser to another one., because the way it loads CSS and HTML into DOM